# What is the difference between "Language: Not specified" & "Language: Not applicable"?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

What is the difference between *Language: Not specified* and *Language: Not applicable*?

There was no such distinction before Drupal 8.

I haven't found any documentation about this. It would be nice to have an explanation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Not applicable** means that we *know* that the very concept of [Human languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language) doesn't apply to this textual piece of content. A relevant example for such content would be [Binary code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_code).

For more see http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-no-language#nonlinguistic.

**Not specified** means we don't know if the text might or might not include human-language content.

For more see http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-no-language#undetermined.

(Both "see more" links are taken from the code documentation in `\Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageInterface` which explains those constants quite well).

Yes, it makes no difference to how content is displayed, but you could treat it differently on your site if you wanted (for example in a view or in custom code).