# "Language neutral" is not available for content

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

On a standard multilingual Drupal installation (Drupal 8.6.10), when editing existing content or creating new content the option *language neutral* isn't available; only the enabled languages and some other options are shown.

> [image: available language options]

How do I select *Language neutral*?

Comment: Have you tried the "Not specified" option ?

Comment: I tried now again and this seems to work. But where's "language neutral" gone? According to this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197521/what-is-the-difference-between-language-not-specified-language-not-applic "not specified" semantically has another meaning than "language neutral".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 8 [LANGUAGE_NONE (neutral) has changed to LANGUAGE_NOT_SPECIFIED, LANGUAGE_NOT_APPLICABLE and LANGUAGE_MULTIPLE](https://www.drupal.org/node/1473200).

I usually use LANGUAGE_NOT_SPECIFIED where I used to use LANGUAGE_NONE in Drupal 7.

[Berdir mentions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197521/what-is-the-difference-between-language-not-specified-language-not-applic) that all those new options makes no difference to how content is displayed, but they let you treat differently to content on your site if you'd wanted to in views, custom code, ...